# Covariance of parameter estimates in Method of Moments

Tags: estimation, covariance, inference, method-of-moments

I have a $3\times1$ vector function $f(x_i;\theta)$ where $X$ is a rv and $\theta$ is $3 \times 1$ parameter vector, such that

\begin{equation} E \, f(X;\theta) = {\bf 0}.\end{equation}

If I have a sample $x_1,\dots,x_N$ from $X$ my understanding is that estimating the LHS in the equation above with the sample average and solving for $\theta$ is the "method of moments" for estimating $\theta$. I.e 
$$ f_N(\theta) = \frac{1}{N} \sum f(x_i;\theta) = {\bf0} \qquad \implies 
 \qquad \hat{\theta} = f_N^{-1}({\bf0}).$$

However I'm not sure how I can estimate the covariance of $\hat{\theta}$. To obtain the estimates I used *fsolve* on the function $f_N$ in matlab. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** Doing some trial and error testing I found that estimating the covariance matrix as

$$ Cov \, (\hat{\theta})= \frac{1}{N}(G_N^T G_N)^{-1}$$ where 
$$ G_N = \nabla_\theta \,  f_N(\theta)$$
is an estimate of $ E\,[\nabla_\theta \, f(X;\theta)]$ gives a feasible result.

Does this make sense?